# ViewPager not responding to touch in layout area created dynamically in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to implement `Viewpager` with  a calendar. I'm using the same three instances of the calendar `Fragment` for testing the `ViewPager` lets call the smooth motion of transferring one fragment to the next SWIPING. the swiping will not work in the area of the fragment that the layout was created dynamically in the fragment itself but the rest of page(above and below the date buttons)the swiping works great! here is some of the code the entire frag code would not fit so had to edit some declarations and button listener methods

// Main Activity

> ```
> public class calenderview extends AppCompatActivity {
> ArrayList<Fragment> fraglist;
>  ViewPager pager;
> calenderviewpageradaptor adaptor;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_calenderview);
>     fraglist = new ArrayList<>();
>     fraglist.add(new Calview_frag()); fraglist.add(new Calview_frag()); fraglist.add(new Calview_frag());
>      adaptor = new calenderviewpageradaptor(getSupportFragmentManager(),fraglist);
>      pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
>     pager.setAdapter(adaptor);
> }
> ```

```
public class calenderviewpageradaptor extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    ArrayList<Fragment>  adaptorlist;
    public calenderviewpageradaptor(FragmentManager fm,ArrayList<Fragment> list){
        super (fm);
        this.adaptorlist = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return 3;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos){
                return adaptorlist.get(pos);

    }
      }
```

}

> public class Calview_frag extends Fragment {
>
> > ```
> >     @Override
> >     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
> >         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
> > ```
>
> ```
>     }
>     private LinearLayout.LayoutParams getdaysLayoutParams() {
>         LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
>
>                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
>
>                 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>
>         buttonParams.weight = 1;
>
>         return buttonParams;
>
>     }
>     private void addDaysinCalendar(ViewGroup.LayoutParams buttonParams, DisplayMetrics metrics) {
>
>         int engDaysArrayCounter = 0;
>
>         LinearLayout.LayoutParams doitwithmarg = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(120,120);
>         doitwithmarg.setMarginStart(cacmarg);
>         LinearLayout.LayoutParams doittoit = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
> ```
>
> ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
>               doittoit.weight=1;
>
> ```
>         for (int weekNumber = 0; weekNumber < 6; ++weekNumber) {
>
>             for (int dayInWeek = 0; dayInWeek < 7; ++dayInWeek) {
>
>                 Button day = new  Button(getContext());
>
>                 day.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>                 day.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREY));
>                 day.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
>                 day.setTextSize((int) metrics.density *5 );
>                 day.setSingleLine();
>
>                 if(dayInWeek!=0){
>                     day.setLayoutParams(doitwithmarg);
>                     Space s = new Space(getContext());
>                     s.setLayoutParams(doittoit);
>                     weeks[weekNumber].addView(s);
>                     days[engDaysArrayCounter] = day;
>                     weeks[weekNumber].addView(day);}
> ```
>
> > ```
> >                   else{
> >                     day.setLayoutParams(doitwithmarg);
> >                     days[engDaysArrayCounter] = day;
> >                     weeks[weekNumber].addView(day);}
> > ```
>
> ```
>                 ++engDaysArrayCounter;
>
>             }
>
>         }
>
>     }
>     private void init(View view) {
>
>         DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
>
>         calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
>
>
>
>         weekOneLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_week_1);
>
>         weekTwoLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_week_2);
>
>         weekThreeLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_week_3);
>
>         weekFourLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_week_4);
>
>         weekFiveLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_week_5);
>
>         weekSixLayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.calendar_week_6);
>
>         currentYear = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.current_date);
>
>         currentMonth = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.current_month);
>
>         currentDateDay = chosenDateDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
>
>
>
>         if (userMonth != 0 && userYear != 0) {
>
>             currentDateMonth = chosenDateMonth = userMonth;
>
>             currentDateYear = chosenDateYear = userYear;
>
>         } else {
>
>             currentDateMonth = chosenDateMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
>
>             currentDateYear = chosenDateYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
>
>         }
>
>
>
>         currentYear.setText("" + chosenDateYear);
>
>         currentMonth.setText(ENG_MONTH_NAMES[currentDateMonth]);
>
>
>         initializeDaysWeeks();
>
>         if (userButtonParams != null) {
>
>             defaultButtonParams = userButtonParams;
>
>         } else {
>
>             defaultButtonParams = getdaysLayoutParams();
>
>         }
>
>         addDaysinCalendar(defaultButtonParams,metrics);
>
>
>
>         initCalendarWithDate(chosenDateYear, chosenDateMonth, chosenDateDay,view);
>
>
>
>     }
>
>
>
>     private void initializeDaysWeeks() {
>
>         weeks = new LinearLayout[6];
>
>         days = new Button[6 * 7];
>
>         weeks[0] = weekOneLayout;
>
>         weeks[1] = weekTwoLayout;
>
>         weeks[2] = weekThreeLayout;
>
>         weeks[3] = weekFourLayout;
>
>         weeks[4] = weekFiveLayout;
>
>         weeks[5] = weekSixLayout;
>
>     }
>     private void initCalendarWithDate(int year, int month, int day, View v) {
>
>         if (calendar == null)
>
>             calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
>
>         calendar.set(year, month, day);
>
>         int daysInCurrentMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
>
>
>         chosenDateYear = year;
>
>         chosenDateMonth = month;
>
>         chosenDateDay = day;
>
>         calendar.set(year, month, 1);
>
>         int firstDayOfCurrentMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
>
>         Log.d(tag,"FFFFFFiiiiiiiiiiirrrrrrrrrrsssssssssst day of month int"+firstDayOfCurrentMonth);
>
>         calendar.set(year, month, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
>         Log.d(tag,"LLLLLLLLLLLLlaaaaasttttttttttt day of month int"+daysInCurrentMonth);
>
>         int dayNumber = 1;
>
>         int daysLeftInFirstWeek = 0;
>         firstDayOfCurrentMonth= firstDayOfCurrentMonth-1;
>         int indexOfDayAfterLastDayOfMonth = 0;
>
>         if (firstDayOfCurrentMonth != 0) {
>
>             daysLeftInFirstWeek = firstDayOfCurrentMonth;
>
>             indexOfDayAfterLastDayOfMonth = daysLeftInFirstWeek + daysInCurrentMonth;
>
>        >                 for (int i = firstDayOfCurrentMonth; i < firstDayOfCurrentMonth + daysInCurrentMonth; ++i) {
>                 //checks all dates of calendar to set background and text colors
>                 if (currentDateMonth == chosenDateMonth
>
>                         && currentDateYear == chosenDateYear
>
>                         && dayNumber == currentDateDay){
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapegrey));
>                     days[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
>
>                 } else {
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>
>                     days[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>                 int[] dateArr = new int[3];
>
>                 dateArr[0] = dayNumber;
>
>                 dateArr[1] = chosenDateMonth;
>
>                 dateArr[2] = chosenDateYear;
>
>                 days[i].setTag(dateArr);
>
>                 days[i].setText(String.valueOf(dayNumber));
>
>
>
>                 days[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>                     @Override
>
>                     public void onClick(View v) {
>                         onDayClick(v);
>
>                     }
>
>                 });
>
>                 ++dayNumber;
>
>             }
>       > 
>             for (int i = 7; i < 7 + daysInCurrentMonth; ++i) {
>
>                 if (currentDateMonth == chosenDateMonth
>
>                         && currentDateYear == chosenDateYear
>
>                         && dayNumber == currentDateDay) {
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshape));
>
>
>                     days[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
>
>                 } else {
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>
>                     days[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>                 int[] dateArr = new int[3];
>
>                 dateArr[0] = dayNumber;
>
>                 dateArr[1] = chosenDateMonth;
>
>                 dateArr[2] = chosenDateYear;
>
>                 days[i].setTag(dateArr);
>
>                 days[i].setText(String.valueOf(dayNumber));
>
>
>
>                 days[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>
>                     @Override
>
>                     public void onClick(View v) {
>                         onDayClick(v);
>
>                     }
>
>                 });
>
>                 ++dayNumber;
>
>             }
>
>         }
> ```
>
> //Displays previous and next month days
>
> ```
>         if (month > 0)
>
>             calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
>
>         else
>
>             calendar.set(year - 1, 11, 1);
>
>         int daysInPreviousMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
>
>
>
>         for (int i = daysLeftInFirstWeek - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
>
>             int[] dateArr = new int[3];
>
>
>
>             if (chosenDateMonth > 0) {
>
>                 if (currentDateMonth == chosenDateMonth - 1
>
>                         && currentDateYear == chosenDateYear
>
>                         && daysInPreviousMonth == currentDateDay) {
>
>                 } else {
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>                 dateArr[0] = daysInPreviousMonth;
>
>                 dateArr[1] = chosenDateMonth - 1;
>
>                 dateArr[2] = chosenDateYear;
>
>             } else {
>
>                 if (currentDateMonth == 11
>
>                         && currentDateYear == chosenDateYear - 1
>
>                         && daysInPreviousMonth == currentDateDay) {
>
>                 } else {
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>                 dateArr[0] = daysInPreviousMonth;
>
>                 dateArr[1] = 11;
>
>                 dateArr[2] = chosenDateYear - 1;
>
>             }
>
>             days[i].setTag(dateArr);
>             days[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.GREY));;
>
>             days[i].setText("");
>
>             days[i].setOnClickListener(null);
>
>         }
>
>         int nextMonthDaysCounter = 1;
>
>         for (int i = indexOfDayAfterLastDayOfMonth; i < days.length; ++i) {
>
>             int[] dateArr = new int[3];
>
>
>             if (chosenDateMonth < 11) {
>
>                 if (currentDateMonth == chosenDateMonth + 1
>
>                         && currentDateYear == chosenDateYear
>
>                         && nextMonthDaysCounter == currentDateDay) {
>
>                     //       days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapegrey));
>                     days[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
>
>                 } else {
>
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>                 dateArr[0] = nextMonthDaysCounter;
>
>                 dateArr[1] = chosenDateMonth + 1;
>
>                 dateArr[2] = chosenDateYear;
>
>             } else {
>
>                 if (currentDateMonth == 0
>
>                         && currentDateYear == chosenDateYear + 1
>
>                         && nextMonthDaysCounter == currentDateDay) {
>                     //        selectedDayButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapegrey));
>                     selectedDayButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
>                     //        days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapegrey));
>                     days[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
>                 } else {
>
>                     days[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundshapeclear));
>
>                 }
>
>
>
>                 dateArr[0] = nextMonthDaysCounter;
>
>                 dateArr[1] = 0;
>
>                 dateArr[2] = chosenDateYear + 1;
>
>             }
>
>             days[i].setTag(dateArr);
>
>             days[i].setText("");
>             days[i].setOnClickListener(null);
>         }
>
>         calendar.set(chosenDateYear, chosenDateMonth, chosenDateDay);
>         currentYear.setText(" " + chosenDateYear);
>         currentMonth.setText(ENG_MONTH_NAMES[chosenDateMonth]);
>
>
>     }
> ```
>
> > ```
> > public Calview_frag() {//required empty constructor
> > }
> > ```
>
> ```
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     // Inflate the layout for this fragment
>     View layoutview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calview,container,false);
>      but = (ImageButton)layoutview.findViewById(R.id.getitbutton);
>      fbut = (ImageButton)layoutview.findViewById(R.id.getit2button);
>     display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
>     Point size = new Point();
>     display.getSize(size);
>     screenheight = size.y;
>     screenwidth = size.x;
>     Log.d(tag,"sssssssssssccreen size  "+screenwidth);
>     if(screenwidth<1300)
>         cacmarg = screenwidth/50;
>     else
>         cacmarg = screenwidth/25;
>     init(layoutview);
>     return layoutview;
> }
> ```
>
> }
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:orientation="vertical">
>     <ScrollView
>         android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
>         app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
>         app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
>
>         <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:background="@android:color/white"
>             android:orientation="vertical">
>             <RelativeLayout
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:orientation="horizontal">
>                 <ImageButton
>                     android:id="@+id/getitbutton"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
>                     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>                     android:src="@drawable/backbutton"
>                     tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
>                 <LinearLayout
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
>
>                     android:gravity="center"
>
>                     android:orientation="horizontal">
>
>                     <TextView
>
>                         android:id="@+id/current_month"
>
>                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                         android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                         android:textSize="28sp" />
>
>
>                     <TextView
>
>                         android:id="@+id/current_date"
>
>                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                         android:paddingLeft="4dp"
>
>                         android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                         android:textSize="28sp" />
>
>                 </LinearLayout>
>
>                 <ImageButton
>                     android:id="@+id/getit2button"
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>                     android:src="@drawable/forwardbutton"
>                     />
>       </RelativeLayout>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7">
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button5"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/sunday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button4"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/monday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button10"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/tuesday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button9"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/wednesday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button8"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/thursday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button7"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/friday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>                 <Button
>
>                     android:id="@+id/button6"
>
>                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                     android:layout_weight="1"
>
>                     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
>
>                     android:text="@string/saturday"
>
>                     android:textColor="@color/bluegrey"
>
>                     android:textSize="16sp" />
>
>
>             </LinearLayout>
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:id="@+id/calendar_week_1"
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7" />
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:id="@+id/calendar_week_2"
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7" />
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:id="@+id/calendar_week_3"
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7" />
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:id="@+id/calendar_week_4"
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7" />
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:id="@+id/calendar_week_5"
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7" />
>
>
>             <LinearLayout
>
>                 android:id="@+id/calendar_week_6"
>
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>
>                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
>                 android:orientation="horizontal"
>
>                 android:weightSum="7" /> </LinearLayout>
>
> </ScrollView>
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to better describe the issue, and to include your code for `Calview_frag`, and the relevant layouts.

Comment: ok mike here is some more code hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

are you passing the instance of the Fragment to the adapter? No I think. You should pass the list of fragments  to the adapter along with fragment manager and should also change the calendarViewPager accordingly.

```
  List<Fragment> fragments =new ArrayList<>();
  fragments.add(Calview_frag());
  fragments.add(Calview_frag());
  fragments.add(Calview_frag());
      calenderviewpageradaptor adaptor =
                new calenderviewpageradaptor(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
```

Comment: Thanks ABr I did try adding the above code in my Activity and modified the constructor it did not make a difference though I posted some more code hopefully that will help

Comment: Also tried getting rid of the scroll view with same results

Comment: I was wondering if I needed some kind of callback in the fragment after it created its views to the viewpager

Comment: hey did you update the code in main activity? coz i didn't see that in the updated code

Comment: here is my updated activity code that did not change the problem. I did not see much on passing a list to the adaptor so I could be way off here